# Understanding the axis rotation in x,y and z axis

Tags: geometry

I start learning 3d software (Blender), where the Y-axis is marked in green, moving along the front-to-back line, and the X-axis is in red, along the side-to-side line, Z is Up and Down The origin is located directly at the center of the grid.

I cant follow when the the tutor says something like 'rotate in Y axis and the value is -90 degree'. How can I visualize minus 90 in any direction when it rotates?

how can he even understand how to put minus when he rotates objects? how can he see the 360 degree in 3d space? both positive and negative?

I badly need to understand it. can anyone make it understandable with plain and simple words with pictures?

I will be eternally grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: in general negative means clockwise, positive means counterclockwise. -90 degree means 90 degree clockwise.

Comment: As Yuval indicates, $-90$ degrees would be $90$ degrees clockwise, or $270$ degrees counter-clockwise. Otherwise, maybe you can cite the tutorial and pick out a particular passage you're having trouble understanding. Have you looked at https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/appendices/rotations.html for instance?

Comment: Brian Tung- it's video tutorial. He was rotating an object in minus 90° in Y axis. :'( Thank you for the link. I am gonna study that.

Comment: Thank you @ Yuval